# Microsoft Visual Studio Report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I need some help to make a report.
So, i have something like this
Column 1 - STOCK
Column 2 - PRICE (per piece)
Column 3 - TOTAL VALUE PER ASSET( stcok * price/piece)
In column 3 i maked this expression (cause the info that i need wasn't in the same db so i have more datasets:
Fields!quantity.Value*Lookup(Fields!name.Value,Fields!name.Value,Fields!obtain_price.Value, "Price")

The problem is that i need a total off column 3 rows (TOTAL VALUE OF THE COMPANY ASSTES) and i dont manage to do it.Any idea how to sum the row off the column 3?

I've search on the internet and tried some solutions but doesnt work.
Group and ADD TOTAL- no
=Sum(Fields!quantity.Value*Lookup(Fields!name.Value,Fields!name.Value,Fields!obtain_price.Value, "Price")) - no

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below one and let me know if that works.

> =SUM(Fields!quantity.Value * Lookup(Fields!name.Value, Fields!name.Value, Fields!obtain_price.Value, "Price"))